# Jquery cannot addClass to li

Tags: jquery, addclass

I got this Jq to add `active` class to `<li>` tag:

```
$("#main-nav li").each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("active");
            //alert(this.href.trim());
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

But somehow it doesn't works, can anyone please look after what's goes wrong?

Comment: try to console.log both `this.href.trim()` and `window.location` inside your `each()`

Comment: `this.href` while `this` is a list item?

Comment: *"Jquery cannot addClass to li"* Yes it can.

Comment: `.href` <-- Undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the anchors, not the list items. The `href` is a property of the anchor. Do that loop and you can then apply `.addClass()` to the closest list item. Also, if you are using jQuery, you may as well use the reliable jQuery `trim()`:

```
$("#main-nav li a").each(function(index) {
    if($.trim(this.href) == window.location) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
        //alert(this.href.trim());
    }
});
```

Comment: I've fixed the indentation, and added `{}` because the OP has commented-out code that looks like it wanted to be in the block (and because one should *always* use the braces).

Comment: I've also added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get href using `this.href.trim()`.you need to use:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href').trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
$("#main-nav li a").each(function(index) {
    if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```